# Changing boolean value inside if-statement?

Tags: java, boolean, conditional-statements

I'm studying for the OCA Java SE7 Associate exam. One of my practice exam questions had the following code snippets:

```
boolean flag = true;
if (flag = false) {
    System.out.println("1");
}
else if (flag) {
    System.out.println("2");
}
else if (!flag) {
    System.out.println("3");
}
else
    System.out.println("4");
```

Notice the `if (flag = false)` conditional. The question asked what the output of this snippet would be. All the numbers were provided as answer choices and then there was a choice that said "compiler error," which is what I selected. I was wrong. The output would be 3. I tested in Eclipse and it also came back with 3.

I then tested with

```
int x = 3;
int y = 1;
if (x = y) {
   // whatever
}
```

and, of course, got an error.

Why can the `flag` be changed from `true` to `false` inside the `if-statement`, but the value of x can't be changed in the similar scenario? Is it because `flag` is a boolean type and x is type `int`? I Googled this, but was unable to find anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the assignment of `x = y` doesn't equate to a `boolean` evaluation.

`if` is expecting the result of the operation to give either a `true` or `false` return.

Something like `if ((x = y) == y)` would work (the evaluation would return `true`)

Comment: Also, is this a good practice? I've never seen it except in studying for this exam.

Comment: @NojoRu no it's very bad practice, People reading (and probably typing) it will think it is `==`.  In fact many static analyzers such as FindBugs will flag this as an error.

Comment: I was hoping you'd say it was a bad practice. Kind of makes me wonder why it's on the exam; just because it can be done doesn't mean it should be.

Comment: @NojoRu It's on the exam because it's highlighting how easy it is to make these kind of mistakes and make sure you're reading ( and understanding) the code

Comment: I've mostly seen this used for reading input, as in `while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

flag = false is an assignment, so it is carried out.  After the assignment on the first if, it evaluates to false because it was just set to it.  For equality it should have been flag == false, but since it was an assignment, the top if was evaluated to false, and since it was changed to false, when you get to !flag, that passes because flag is no longer true, and it prints 3.

You got an error with if(x = y) because after the assignment, the value couldn't be evaluated as a boolean outcome whereas if(flag = false) can evaluate to boolean after the assignment.

The big thing to remember about high-level languages is that it takes more than one low-level statement to perform the logic of even a simple if, and with the assignment case, there is a minimum of 2 operations going on, first the assignment, then the equality.

Answer (score 0):

`if (flag = false)` will set the `flag` variable to false, then check `if(flag)`.

You are suggesting doing `if(x = 1)` which could set `x` to 1, but `if(x)` is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

It would print `3` because the boolean variable is assigned `false` (and checked for true) then checked for false and finally for `!false` which is `true`.